# Scala Trait type mismatch

Tags: scala, scala-generics

I have some Kafka Channel hierarchy that I am using in my project:

My base trait is:

```
trait SendChannel[A, B] extends CommunicationChannel {
  def send(data:A): B
}
```

Now I have a common kafka send Channel like

```
trait CommonKafkaSendChannel[A, B, Return] extends SendChannel[A, Return] {
val channelProps: KafkaSendChannelProperties
val kafkaProducer: Producer[String, B]
 override def close(): Unit = kafkaProducer.close()
}
```

Now there are 2 variants of CommanKafkaSendChannel, one is with callback and one is with Future:

```
trait KafkaSendChannelWithFuture[A, B] extends CommonKafkaSendChannel[A, B, Future[RecordMetadata]] {
override def send(data: A): Future[RecordMetadata] = Future {
  kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, B](channelProps.topic)).get
}
}
```

`KafkaSendChannelWithCallback` definition:

```
object KafkaSendChannelWithCallback {

def apply[A, B](oChannelProps: KafkaSendChannelProperties,
              oKafkaProducer: Producer[String, B],
              oCallback: Callback): KafkaSendChannelWithCallback[A, B] =
new KafkaSendChannelWithCallback[A,B] {
  override val channelProps: KafkaSendChannelProperties = oChannelProps
  override val kafkaProducer: Producer[String, B] = oKafkaProducer
  override val callback: Callback = oCallback
}
}

trait KafkaSendChannelWithCallback[A, B] extends CommonKafkaSendChannel[A, B, Unit] {

  val callback: Callback

override def send(data: A): Unit =
kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, B](channelProps.topic), callback)
}
```

Now based on the configuration value I select the proper type of channel on run time like below. I am creating actor with right type of channel which will send the data to kafka:

```
  val sendChannel = kafkaChannel.channel(config, actorSystem).fold(
    error => {
      logger.error("Exception while instantiating the KafkaSendChannel")
      throw error
    },
    success => success
  )

actor = actorSystem.actorOf(IngestionActor.props(config, sendChannel), name = ACTOR_NAME)
```

Actor definition:

```
object IngestionRouterActor {
  def props[V](config: Config, sendChannel: SendChannel[V, Unit]): Props =
Props(classOf[IngestionActor[V]], config, sendChannel)
}
```

The problem is when I use `KafkaSendChannelWithCallback` my code compiles properly however when I use `KafkaSendChannelWithFuture` it gives me below error on `actor =` declaration:

> [error]IngestionActor.scala:32: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
>   [error]  found   : KafkaSendChannelWithFuture[String,V]
>   [error]  required: SendChannel[V,Unit]

As both the channel definitions are extended from `SendChannel`, this code should have compiled without any error. I am not sure why it is not compiling. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Props` for `IngestionActor` takes a `SendChannel[V, Unit]`. Passing in a `KafkaSendChannelWithCallback` to this argument works because it's a `SendChannel[V, Unit]`.

On the other hand, `KafkaSendChannelWithFuture` is a `SendChannel[V, Future[RecordMetadata]]`. A `SendChannel[V, Future[RecordMetadata]]` is *not* a `SendChannel[V, Unit]`.

One option is to redefine the `Props` to take a `SendChannel[V, Any]`, since `Any` is a supertype of both `Unit` and `Future`:

```
def props[V](config: Config, sendChannel: SendChannel[V, Any]): Props = ???
```

At this point, the compiler is still unhappy because `SendChannel`, being a generic type, is invariant by default. In other words, neither `SendChannel[V, Unit]` nor `SendChannel[V, Future[RecordMetadata]]` are of type `SendChannel[V, Any]`.

To change that, make `SendChannel` covariant on the second type parameter (by adding a `+` in front of the `B`):

```
trait SendChannel[A, +B] extends CommunicationChannel {
  def send(data: A): B
}
```

Comment: Hi @chunjef, thanks for your response. You mentioned `since Any is a supertype of both Unit and Future` which is try as `Any` is supertype but why `neither SendChannel[V, Unit] nor SendChannel[V, Future[RecordMetadata]] are of type SendChannel[V, Any]` this is false?

Comment: I made the change that you suggested, is there any change required in the `props` which is still having `SendChannel[V, Unit]` becuase I still get the same error.

Comment: @Explorer: Please read my answer more carefully. I address both of your comments in the answer.